# Cassandra - Slow Compaction and Flush Throughputs

Tags: performance, cassandra

I'm experiencing slow overall throughputs in my (single) cassandra node. I'm currently using cassandra 3.7 on a Debian 8 VM, 16GB ram, 8 cores (4+4HT), two dedicated 7200RPM spindles (the VM has 3 virtual disks: `sda` is the OS, `sdb` and `sdc` are two other virtual disks each one in a different spindle, and `sda` and `sdb` are in the same spindle). Cassandra is configured with two data directories, so in a JBOD configuration.

I took every advice I could find online but the system still lacks performance. What I mean is that the system cannot tolerate long running jobs and its average throughput is around 15MB/s, no "batches misusing" so far, but it can get peaks at 70MB/s when the node is not performing any compaction job.

In order to eliminate every potential bottleneck I moved my "data pusher" to the host itself, and reduced it down to a simple multithreaded client that pushes random data at 4k chunks with async writes only. I also moved the commitlog to a ramdisk, removing any commitlog IOPS constraint (that  seemed to me were my n.1 bottleneck, at least for my workload)

This is the output of `dstat -lrvn -D total,sda,sdb,sdc 10` while the system is under stress (pushed 56GB of random data, and still pushing more data):

```
---load-avg--- --io/total-----io/sda------io/sdb------io/sdc-- ---procs--- ------memory-usage----- ---paging-- -dsk/total----dsk/sda-----dsk/sdb-----dsk/sdc-- ---system-- ----total-cpu-usage---->
 1m   5m  15m | read  writ: read  writ: read  writ: read  writ|run blk new| used  buff  cach  free|  in   out | read  writ: read  writ: read  writ: read  writ| int   csw |usr sys idl wai hiq siq>
16.3 22.1 25.2| 917   226 :   0  2.60 : 347   139 : 570  84.3 | 13 1.9  50|11.6G 2976k 4012M  166M|   0     0 |  44M   44M:   0    52k:  17M   31M:  27M   13M|  36k   60k| 29   6  48  16   0   0>
14.6 21.6 25.0| 744   142 :   0  0.90 :2.00  75.0 : 742  65.9 |1.8 4.2  20|11.6G 2904k 4050M  151M|   0     0 |  35M   20M:   0    20k:  16k 5541k:  35M   15M|  23k   40k| 15   4  49  32   0   0>
13.2 21.0 24.8| 731  91.0 :0.80  4.70 : 127  22.9 : 603  63.4 |0.8 2.8  23|11.6G 2712k 4028M  171M|   0     0 |  34M   26M:  36k   52k:5250k 6631k:  29M   19M|5660  8099 |  8   2  63  28   0   0>
12.5 20.8 24.7| 536   131 :   0  6.00 :68.1  29.2 : 468  95.8 |1.9 2.1  47|11.6G 2728k 4032M  164M|   0     0 |  25M   48M:   0    74k:2744k 3856k:  22M   44M|6877    11k| 14   2  61  23   0   0>
```

From what I see the compaction activity happens at low rate, around 20MB/s on average (yep there are some spikes at 50MB/s or more, but they very rarely happen). I removed the throttling of the compaction throughput from the YAML, but it didn't increase. I also notice that the compaction happens all on one disk, eg reading AND compacting tables ALL on `sdb` or `sdc`, while it seems more appropriate to read from one data directory and write to the other in order to avoid read/write seek conflicts (yes, I tried to configured concurrent_compactors: 1).

My client output after a 60GB says:

```
Row 11930000 written (3914 ops/s, 15,29 MB/s)
```

Now I stopped, let cassandra do its job, and started it again:

```
Row 670000 written (10931 ops/s, 42,70 MB/s)
```

When compaction triggers in I get a drop:

```
Row 1640000 written (5543 ops/s, 21,65 MB/s)
```

and again a dstat output confirms slow compaction:

```
 1m   5m  15m | read  writ: read  writ: read  writ: read  writ|run blk new| used  buff  cach  free|  in   out | read  writ: read  writ: read  writ: read  writ| int   csw |usr sys idl wai hiq siq>
24.9 23.9 17.3|72.6  44.4 :0.52  4.23 :20.4  17.4 :51.7  22.8 |  0 0.0  31|12.9G 4636k 2720M  195M|   0     0 |3824k   10M:  13k  679k:1002k 4149k:2809k 5188k|  16k   29k| 16   2  77   4   0   0>
29.0 24.8 17.6| 530   300 :   0  5.00 : 234   105 : 296   189 | 10 2.9  39|12.9G 4644k 2188M  638M|   0     0 |  23M   83M:   0    55k:9746k   19M:  14M   63M|  44k   62k| 24   7  48  21   0   0>
29.8 25.1 17.8| 805   325 :25.2  2.10 : 235   159 : 545   164 |9.3 6.1  40|12.9G 4948k 2715M  179M|   0     0 |  33M   56M:1241k   46k:9721k   25M:  22M   31M|  59k  100k| 38  10  33  18   0   0>
25.6 24.4 17.7| 507   302 :12.6  5.00 : 215   126 : 280   170 | 12 3.1  47|12.9G 4956k 2710M  133M|   0     0 |  21M   58M: 968k   81k:8964k   22M:  11M   36M|  54k   88k| 33   9  42  16   0   0>
22.5 23.7 17.5| 764   245 :0.10  3.30 : 535   115 : 229   127 | 21 2.9  48|12.9G 4976k 2726M  180M|   0     0 |  31M   43M: 410B   61k:  22M   23M:9343k   20M|  32k   59k| 27   6  52  15   0   0>
29.7 25.2 18.1| 987   339 :   0  5.20 : 605   164 : 382   169 | 18 3.7  47|13.0G 4992k 2633M  164M|   0     0 |  40M   64M:   0    68k:  25M   39M:  15M   25M|  65k  106k| 37  10  38  15   0   0>
25.8 24.5 17.9| 753   297 :   0  2.80 : 403   144 : 351   150 | 14 4.1  55|13.0G 5000k 2650M  170M|   0     0 |  30M   74M:   0    56k:  16M   36M:  14M   37M|  40k   71k| 31   6  38  25   0   0>
22.6 23.8 17.8| 718   207 :   0  3.50 : 521   128 : 197  74.9 |7.7 2.5  47|13.0G 5016k 2517M  287M|   0     0 |  29M   51M:   0    71k:  21M   37M:8232k   14M|  30k   51k| 25   5  54  16   0   0>
```

I tried to increase the memtable flushers count and tune the cleanup ratio, but they seems to have impact only on the beginning of the compaction.

I monitored the CPU usage and cassandra approaches the 400% during initial writes (when peaking up to 70MB/s, the client consumes up to 150%), and then settles to around 150%, with "negative" peaks of 25% when compacting tables (client rests.....)

So it seems to me that the overall process is disk I/O "throughput" bound and not CPU bound, because I'm maxing out the IOPS of both disks (see dstat), however I cannot get throughput from these IOPS, even if cassandra should perform large sequential writings at the speed of... light!

How can I force cassandra to flush data at maximum speed in order to allow me to push data faster?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

The average output gets down to 11MB/s. However, configuring disks in RAID-0 increases the throughput up to a sustained 31MB/s:

```
3030567 rows: avg 8145 ops/s, avg 31,82 MB/s, avg reads = 0 ops/s, avg writes = 8145 ops/s
3034439 rows: avg 8103 ops/s, avg 31,65 MB/s, avg reads = 0 ops/s, avg writes = 8103 ops/s
3059090 rows: avg 8147 ops/s, avg 31,83 MB/s, avg reads = 0 ops/s, avg writes = 8147 ops/s
3064226 rows: avg 8122 ops/s, avg 31,73 MB/s, avg reads = 0 ops/s, avg writes = 8122 ops/s
3089627 rows: avg 8168 ops/s, avg 31,91 MB/s, avg reads = 0 ops/s, avg writes = 8168 ops/s
```

Here's again the output of `dstat`:

```
---load-avg--- --io/total-----io/sda------io/md0-- ---procs--- ------memory-usage----- ---paging-- -dsk/total----dsk/sda-----dsk/md0-- ---system-- ----total-cpu-usage---- -net/total-
 1m   5m  15m | read  writ: read  writ: read  writ|run blk new| used  buff  cach  free|  in   out | read  writ: read  writ: read  writ| int   csw |usr sys idl wai hiq siq| recv  send
6.61 6.40 3.83| 292   186 :14.6  0.40 : 283   193 |4.2 1.5 1.6|12.0G 1548k 3685M  147M|   0     0 |  47M   84M: 255k 8192B:  46M   82M|  39k   59k| 22   5  50  22   0   0|  52B  123B
6.06 6.29 3.82| 289   165 :22.8  0.70 : 273   173 |4.2 2.9 1.5|11.9G 1420k 3610M  281M|   0     0 |  45M   75M: 146k 9830B:  45M   77M|  21k   39k| 16   4  58  23   0   0| 884B   68B
5.74 6.22 3.82| 278   172 :20.2  0.70 : 265   177 |3.3 2.5 3.9|11.9G 1124k 3709M  162M|   0     0 |  44M   80M: 294k 9011B:  44M   79M|  34k   51k| 19   4  52  25   0   0|  32B   83B
5.47 6.14 3.82| 351   178 :52.6  1.50 : 305   180 |6.0 2.1   0|11.9G 1092k 3701M  175M|   0     0 |  38M   79M: 669k   26k:  37M   78M|  27k   59k| 24   4  53  18   0   0|  51B   99B
5.09 6.04 3.82| 300   176 :25.4  0.40 : 282   190 |4.2 2.4   0|12.0G  656k 3655M  182M|   0     0 |  45M   80M: 228k 3686B:  45M   82M|  32k   60k| 21   5  55  19   0   0| 228B  103B
4.84 5.95 3.81| 294   172 :24.8  0.50 : 275   175 |3.1 2.4   0|12.0G  648k 3642M  173M|   0     0 |  45M   80M: 264k 8602B:  45M   79M|  38k   48k| 17   4  57  22   0   0|  32B   59B
5.27 6.01 3.85| 295   175 :25.3  1.20 : 276   184 |2.4 2.7 0.7|12.0G  532k 3636M  180M|   0     0 |  44M   80M: 235k   19k:  44M   81M|  33k   59k| 21   4  54  21   0   0|  46B  123B
5.32 5.99 3.87| 315   169 :23.7  0.40 : 301   175 |4.6 2.2 1.4|11.9G  536k 3742M  162M|   0     0 |  50M   76M: 506k 8192B:  49M   76M|  28k   44k| 20   4  52  24   0   0|  60B   99B
```

The RAID0 configuration mitigates the reads/writes clashes, and it seems this is not a "tuning" problem, but a bad write performance of C*.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

It seems that this "one disk only" compaction is intended to be as it is:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improving-jbod
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6696